# Passing data from one view to another in Laravel

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, parameter-passing

I have a `Controller` that parses an XML and returns a view with a list of names and URLs.

```
return view('view_1',compact('myList'));
```

View_1 will have a `form` with parameters `method="POST" action="goToView_2"`

Then I get some information from my `view_2` through a `POST`, but I still want to keep `$myList` so that `view_2` view uses it aswell.

How do I pass `$myList` from the first view to the next through a controller?

Comment: Could you post your controller codes too?

Comment: instead of mapping goToView_2 directly from the Routes.php. You can use the controller to map the action "goToView_2" and include the $myList when returning the view. you can set $myList as global variable if is static other wise you can pass it as parameter to the next view. Please post your code so I can help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to have multi-step form of some kind.

I would store the data in the session and easily access it in the second controller or in the view (although not recommended).

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session#using-the-session

PS. I personally love using the global session helper.